# how to get elements from JSONObject and write it to file

Tags: java, stringbuilder

i have a following JSONObject

```
                {"elements": [
              {
                "name": "StartLabelFormat",
                "value": "^XA"
              },
              {
                "name": "shipperAddressLine1",
                "value": "Street1",
                "format": {"Text": {
                  "orientation": "N",
                  "height": "28",
                  "width": 20,
                  "fontname": 0,
                  "y": 373,
                  "x": 20
                }}
              },
              {
                "name": "EndLabelFormat",
                "value": "^XZ"
              }
            ]}
```

Now i want to get element from this Object and write it to a file.
For Example, for this block

```
 {
                "name": "shipperAddressLine1",
                "value": "Street1",
                "format": {"Text": {
                  "orientation": "N",
                  "height": "28",
                  "width": 21,
                  "fontname": 0,
                  "y": 373,
                  "x": 20
                }}
              },
```

I want to write in file as
^FT  20, 373 ^A0N, 28, 21 ^FDStreet1^FS.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: This is not a coding service. Do some work yourself.

Comment: Could you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to do it ?

- If you meet `{}` in your code , you can use `JSONObject` to parse it .
- If you meet `[]` in your code , you can use `JSONArray` to parse it .
- And if you meet `[]` in your code , you can use `for loop` to get value in it .
- And you should use `try catch` in your code .

Try this in your code .

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray elements = jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements");
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = elements.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonObject1.optString("name");
            String value = jsonObject1.optString("value");
            JSONObject format = jsonObject1.optJSONObject("format");
            JSONObject Text = format.optJSONObject("Text");
            String orientation = Text.optString("orientation");
            String height = Text.optString("height");
            String width = Text.optString("width");
        }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note**

- And use `optString` and `optJSONObject` in your code . If `format` is `null` ,it will not return error .
- And you can judge that `JSONArray`'s `length` is not 0 and not `null` in the code .

Comment: Thanks for the help @KeLiuyue, I am to able get data, but how should I write it to file.There are more elements in JSONArray which may contains formats or maynot. Basically i have to write a file from this JsonObject,like
    `^XA `
    `^LH16,12 `
    `^LL1212`
    `^FT  20, 313 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FD Street1 ^FS`
    `^FT  20, 343 ^A0N, 28, 20 ^FD US ^FS`
    `^XZ

Answer (score -1):

To get this element from JsonArray

```
JsonObject yourElement = yourJsonArray.get(index);
```

Simply, you can use gson library for parsing json to objects.

```
public class Staff {

private String name;
private String value;

//...
```

and use Gson

```
String jsonInString = " {
            "name": "shipperAddressLine1",
            "value": "Street1"
          }";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(yourElement.toString() , Staff.class);
```

After that you can write in file by using your custom toString() method inside Staff class.
P.S. to convert JsonObject to String you can use also toString() method.